# Can't find Resource Bundle at release time

Tags: java, maven, junit, build, bamboo

I have a multi-module Maven project that looks like this:

```
reactor
 | core
 | console
 | custom-maven-plugin (depends on core)
 | test-deployment
```

I have a resource bundle with the base name `login` which I exclude from Git, because it contains passwords. In my project, the file is located in `core/src/test/resources` and I have a test class, which uses it like so:

```
public abstract class TestBase {
    private static final ResourceBundle constants = ResourceBundle.getBundle("constants");
    private static final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("login");
    private Connection connection;

    // ...

    Connection getConnection() {
        // Connection will be created in another method, this one just returns it.
    }
}

public class ActualTest extends TestBase {
    // Uses the connection in tests here.
}
```

Now if I execute `mvn package` for the whole project, the tests all finish correctly.

On my build server, I have a script which creates the `login.properties`, since it's not included in the cloned project:

```
printf "userName=$bamboo_login_userName\npassword=$bamboo_login_password" > core/src/test/resources/login.properties
```

The build server executed `mvn clean release:prepare release:perform`, but at this point, the build fails to this exception:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name login, locale en_US
```

I already checked the directory `core/src/test/resources` *and* `core/target/test-classes`, but the file is there. For some reason, the resource bundle for `constants` doesn't throw an exception, which tells me, there is a problem with how I create that login file.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be generating your login.properties in `main` instead of `test`?

```
printf "userName=$bamboo_login_userName\npassword=$bamboo_login_password" > core/src/main/resources/login.properties
```

Comment: The classes `TestBase` and `ActualTest` are located in the folder `core/src/test/java`. This means, the resource bundles must be located in `core/src/test/resources`. If I put it in the `core/src/main/resources` folder, the classes wouldn't have access to it anymore.